# Is Prime Method with Ruby

Tags: ruby, while-loop

I am trying to write a concise is_prime method, which determines if an integer is prime. (I've written the method below). I've used a 'while' loop to finish off the method, but what I really want to use is a 'for' loop – similar to how it would be coded in java. (Java for loop is included below).

My immediate question is how to make my ruby is_prime method more concise and use a for loop instead of a while. My secondary question is how to translate java for loops into ruby (could I use an each method)?

```
//java (replaces only the while loop below and not the entire is_prime method)
for(int d=3; d*d<=n; d+=2){
   if(n%d==0) return false;
}

#ruby
def is_prime(n)
  if (n < 2)
    return false
  end
  if (n == 2)
    return true
  end
  if (n%2 == 0)
    return false
  end
  d = 3
  while (d*d < n) do
    if(n%d==0)
      return false
    end
    d+=2
  end
  return true;
end

puts is_prime(5) # true
puts is_prime(13) # true
puts is_prime(10) # false
puts is_prime(28) # false
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a more approapriate place for Code Review questions.

Comment: IMO, don't try to make Ruby code look just like Java's. It can be much more cooler and expressive in the Ruby way. So know more about Ruby (if you are gonna use it often).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're just writing this method for fun, but in case you need to get work done, [Ruby has a built in prime library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html).

```
require 'prime'

Prime.prime?(2**31-1)
#=> true
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    def is_prime n
      for d in 2..(n - 1)
       if (n % d) == 0
        return false
       end
      end
     true
   end
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: it is sufficient to check for sqrt(n).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to write it:

```
def is_prime?(number)
  (2..number-1).each {|n| return false if number <= 1 || number % n == 0}
  return true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ruby for loop like this:

```
def is_prime(n)
  return false if n < 2 or n % 2 == 0
  return true if n == 2
  for d in 3..Math.sqrt(n).to_i
    return false if n % d == 0
  end
  return true;
end
```

You will know how to use loop in ruby from [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm).